# Why is it beneficial to be able to change the order of integration for a triple integral? Explain.

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you illuminate your mean a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to integrate the function $f(x,y) = e^{y^2}$

Over the triangluar region in the plane bounded by lines $x = y, y = 1, x = 0$

It might seem natural to set it up like:

$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 e^{y^2}\ dy\ dx$

But $\int e^{y^2} \ dy$ doesn't integrate into elementary functions.

but if you swap the order of integration.

$\int_0^1 \int_0^y e^{y^2}\ dx\ dy$

Is fairly easy to integrate.